# RSSBus Connect could not able to create file

Tags: rss

I am integrating my code for creating file in RSSBus | Connect. 
Below is my Javascript Code:

```
    <?php
       $header     = base64_encode(USERNAME. ":" . USERPASS);
       $content    = base64_encode('Welcome');
     ?>
     <div id="result">
     Content will loading here...    
     </div>
     <script src="../../../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){

     var token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
     var surl = 'http://xxxxxxx/api.rsc/files?x-rssbus-uthtoken='+token+'&@jsonp';
      var postdata = {
         PortId:     "xxxxxxxxx", 
         Folder:     "Send", 
         Filename:   "testfile.xml",
         Content:    "<?php echo $content; ?>"
     };

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: surl,
         processData: false,
         contentType: 'application/json',     
         data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
         dataType: 'jsonp',        
         crossDomain: true,  

     }).done(function(data){

         var data = JSON.stringify(data);
         $("#result").html("<pre>"+data+"</pre>");

     }).fail(function(data){

         console.log('fail'); 
     });

     });
     </script>
```

I have run this javascript in php. All code works perfectly but the file could not be created in "Send" folder. i am also getting proper response but it converts into GET parameter and error gives like "405 Method Not Allowed" comes in all response. when successfully response comes but the file is not creating in folder.

Please provide me solutions ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with below code. I was success to crate file.

```
$url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api.rsc/files';            
$portid     = 'PORT';
$folder     = 'Send or Receiver Folder name';
$filename   = 'mytest.xml';
$content    = base64_encode('file content');    
$fields = array( 'PortId' => $portid, 'Filename' => $filename, 'Folder' => $folder, 'Content' => $content);    
$data_string = json_encode($fields);    
$header = array('Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode(AS2_USERNAME. ":" . AS2_USERPASS)
                ,'Content-Type: application/json'
                ,'Content-Length: '.strlen($data_string)
                );    
$ch = curl_init();     

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(!curl_errno($ch)){
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    _printr($info);
    echo "<br /><br />";
}else{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}    
curl_close($ch);
var_dump( $result );
```

Comment: Thanks for providing answer. and Yes its working perfectly. Thanks.